# Rewriting regex to remove c#6 dependency

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
string ContactFirst = "Johnathan";
string TheSearchString = "John";
Regex.IsMatch(ContactFirst, $@"\b{TheSearchString}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
//should return false
```

The problem is that this regex required adding C#6 to the project, just for this one line of code to work. Is there a way to make it work with C#5?

Comment: `string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", TheSearchString)`

Comment: You can also just add the literals yourself by using '\' to escape them: `"\\b{TheSearchString}\\b"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C#6 supports interpolated string literals (`$"..."`), and to make the code compatible with the earlier C# versions, you may use [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

I also suggest using [`Regex.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the `TheSearchString` is a literal string:

```
Regex.IsMatch(ContactFirst, 
          string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(TheSearchString)), 
          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of using Regex.Escape?

Comment: `Regex.Escape()` adds a backslash before special symbols that may turn out to be special regex metacharacters, and "corrupt" the resulting regex. You added some examples after I posted the answer, so that is probably not your case. Still, it is best practice to use `Regex.Escape()` when inserting *literal* strings into the regex pattern.